# Why does method MultipartFormDataContent.ReadAsStringAsync return different values before sending http-request and after its receiving?

Tags: c#, multipartform-data

I have such case: I compare hash of http-request content before sending and after receiving.
If content is multipart form data content, then hashes aren't equal because content differs.

This is how I build request content (.net 5):

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(streamsInfoToSend);
var jsonContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, JsonContent);

var multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multiPartContent.Add(jsonContent);
streamsToSend.ForEach(s =>
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(s);
    multiPartContent.Add(new StreamContent(ms));
});
var body = await multiPartContent.ReadAsStringAsync(token);
```

This is how I read it after receiveng of request (.net framework 4.7):

```
var requestContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Values of body and requestContent are different (requestContent's size is smaller).
Why?

Comment: In what way are the contents different?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I compare their hash in this way


`using (var hasher = SHA1.Create())
{
    var hash = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}`

And size of string after receiving request is smaller than original string.

Comment: Yes, But what is actually different? Look at the bodies, and compare them using a diff tool.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Text parts are same, but binary parts are different.